# Exponential objects of internal objects respecting evaluation (2-exponentials?)

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, higher-category-theory

Let $(F,+_F)$, and $(G,+_G)$ be two commutative internal monoids in Sets. Set being cartesian closed, I can form $G^F$ as a set.

My question is simple:
is there a canonical/universal way to enforce that $G^F$ inherits an internal monoidal structure $(G^F, +_{G^F})$ induced by $(F,+_F)$ and $(G,+_G)$ in such a way that it preserves evaluation. That is, in such a way that for all generalized elements $f, g: 1 \rightarrow G^F$, $x, y: 1 \rightarrow F$, $ev \circ (Id \times +_F) \circ (f,x,y) = +_G \circ (ev \times ev)\circ (Id_{G^F} \times \sigma \times Id_F) \circ (\Delta_{G^F} \times Id_F \times Id_F ) \circ (f,x,y)$, where $\sigma$ is the swap (this one means that the elements of the exponential objects are morphism of internal monoids $f(x+_F y) = f(x) +_G f(y)$ ). I also want to impose that it preserves the evaluation: $ev\circ (+_{G^F} \times Id_F)  \circ (f,g,x) = +_G \circ (ev \times ev) \circ (Id_{G^F} \times \sigma \times Id_F)\circ (Id_{G^F} \times Id_{G^F} \times \Delta_F) \circ (f,g,x)$, that is in more usual notations $(f+_{G^F}g)(x) = f(x) +_G f(x)$.

Eventually, what I would like to do is to have a 2-sketch of such exponential preserving evaluation objects, that is, a purely syntactic characterization, without having to impose all of the previous equations explicitely: indeed, recalling that an internal monoid in Set (or any other category $\mathcal{C}$) is a functor preserving products from the category of one monoid object to Set, we can see $F$ and $G$ above as two such functors. A natural transformation between the two previous functors being a morphism of monoid, one could always enforce the two required equations above as equations involving different functors preserving products and natural transformations between them in a well chosen 2-category. Obviously, it is already easy to "1-sketch" what it means to an exponential object preserving evaluation by adding everything we want, but this doesn't give me an elegant way to "2-sketch" it without having to enforce all such equations and objects.

I suspect that what I'm looking for is related to the idea of 2-exponential (that is, an exponential that sees further than just the first layer of structure, i.e., it also sees that you have some form of evaluation), but I have no idea if such concepts has already been found/formalized in a satisfying way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; the addition $G^F \times G^F \to G^F$ you want can be defined as the transpose of  the morphism $G^F \times G^F \times F \to G$ expressing the pointwise formula which is fairly straightforward. Does that satisfy your goal, or are you trying to ask about something else? (or have I overlooked something?)

Comment: (P.S. I'm used to the identity being part of the monoid structure, so calling $(F, +)$ an internal monoid looks wrong to me)

Comment: Mind you expliciting the morphism you take the transpose of? Maybe I totally missed something easy there.

Comment: The one sending $(f,g,x)$ to $f(x) + g(x)$. It can be decomposed as $$ G^F \times G^F \times F \to (G^F \times F) \times (G^F \times F) \to G \times G \to G $$ where the first map just rearranges the product (duplicating $F$ in the process) and the others are evaluation then addition.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work straightforwardly as a definition of $+_{G^F}$. This gives us the direction "knowing $F$ and $G$ as internal monoid allows us to give a structure of internal monoid in $G^F$". What interests me is more the other way around tho, starting from an exponential $G^F$ that is also an internal monoid (say), can we show that the internal product is inherited from two internal monoids? It should be feasible with such tranpose, thanks. (Btw, you're right for the units, i didn't write them by lazyness)

Comment: Surely not; there are usually lots of monoid structures on $G^F$. A related question that maybe has an affirmative answer is if you instead considered the classifying topos of the theory with two commutative monoids. Letting $(F,+)$ and $(G,+)$ refer to the corresponding monoids from the universal model, you could then ask what monoid structures exist on $G^F$. I have no clue whether it would be unique or not.

Comment: Yes but I think it should be feasible to look at the conditions required on the product map for it to be inherited from internal monoids! Or maybe I'm too optimistic?